# Getting every single article key?

Tags: php, sql, xml, import

I try to get every single article number from this XML structure in my db:

```
<Article Key="8075581" Status="active"> ... </Article>
<Article Key="8050939" Status="active"> ... </Article>
<Article Key="8047871" Status="active"> ... </Article>
<Article Key="8058626" Status="active"> ... </Article>
```

First, I've tried to get the value of the attribute "Key" and insert it in my db:

```
<?php

<...>

$xmlstring = simplexml_load_file("export.xml");
foreach($xmlstring->children() as $article) {
    $articleid = (string) $article['Key'];
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO articles (articelnr)
VALUES ($articleid)";

<...>

$conn->close();
```

But this just insert the last value:

```
ID KEY
01 8058626
```

Can someone help me to get every "Key" separate in the db. Like this:

```
ID KEY
01 8075581
02 8050939
03 8047871
04 8058626
```

THANKS

Comment: If you put the insert code in foreach it will work, how you've set it now it will loop through the foreach and give you the last value

Comment: @Chiba Andrei: This doesn't work for me, it still takes the last value when I put it in the foreach.

Comment: i guess you are using `mysqli_query` to insert or something similar, you have to put that in the foreach too not just the variable `$sql`

Comment: Well.. That makes sense, sry :D Thanks for your advise, it works out fine!

Comment: consider updating your question or posting an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <?php
    <...>
    $xmlstring = simplexml_load_file("export.xml");
    foreach($xmlstring->children() as $article) {
        $articleid = (string) $article['Key'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO articles (articelnr) VALUES ($articleid)";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "\n\n### DONE ###\n\n";}
        else {
                echo "\n\n### ERROR ###" . $sql . "\n" . $conn->error . "\n\n";}

    }
    <...>
    $conn->close();
```

Worked! I've put the insert method into the foreach.